# Can anybody recommend a good auxiliary monitor for a 2017 21 inch iMac?

Tags: monitors

Can anybody recommend a good auxiliary monitor (single display space mode) for a 2017 21" iMac, that isn't either enormous or extremely expensive (or both)?

I've been using an old ViewSonic VA912b since I got the thing, but the resolution is so much lower (0.294mm dot pitch) than that of the iMac itself (0.120mm dot pitch) that it's (to put it mildly) less-than-ideal, and given that we've already had one or two old 912s blow their inverters, I'd rather like to have something better sooner, rather than later.

I wouldn't mind one that works in portrait orientation, although that's a relatively minor consideration.

Comment: What you are asking is really hard, iMacs already have good screens

Comment: Yes. So good that most of what is available for use as an auxiliary screen is not going to match the resolution. That's the point.